# Amp-image-lightbox = PageSpeed Insights warning

Tags: amp-html

A slideshow built with `<amp-image-lightbox>` enlarges a thumbnail to a bigger image. The problem is that the thumbnail is full weight Ko, as much as the enlarged image. This triggers a warning in the Google PageSpeed Insights: "too much Ko". How can I do to display the small image with less Ko according to its sizes in `px` using [`<amp-image-lightbox>`](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-image-lightbox/)?

Comment: What does "Ko" stand for?

Comment: I mean kilo-octet or kilo-byte.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense... I was reading it as knockout.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `srcset` attribute as shown [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/) to accomplish that. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried srcset but it doesn't work: a small image gets blurred once enlarged, that's all.

Comment: Yeah! It works with srcset this way:

<amp-img srcset="photos/photo_1.jpg 700w, thumbnails/photo_1.jpg 300w" alt="" width="300" height="200" on="tap:lightbox" role="button" tabindex="0"></amp-img>